# Remove all users in bulk (foreach)

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I need to remove all users from my Microsoft Team in one command. The get-teamuser (first row) is giving me all the members. But I can't figure out how to now remove all in a loop. Think this should be something like the second row. But not sure how to do this.

Hope someone can help me with this issue.

```
Get-TeamUser -GroupId a4f03b48-49ae-4f06-949f-81b4940e17b6 | where-object {$_.role -eq "member"}

#Get-content c:\list.txt |foreach{Remove-TeamUser -GroupId a4f03b48-49ae-4f06-949f-81b4940e17b6 -User $_}
```

Comment: Have you ran the help for `Remove-TeamUser`? It may tell you what type of objects it accepts and one might be the object returned from your `Get-TeamUser`. Can you just pipe it to it: `Get-TeamUser .... | Remove-TeamUser`?

Comment: Yes I did and I can remove single users without any problem. But I need to remove all users in bulk from a team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$users = Get-TeamUser -GroupId a4f03b48-49ae-4f06-949f-81b4940e17b6 | where-object {$_.role -eq "member"}
Foreach ($user in $users)
{
$UPN = $user.userprinciplename

Remove-TeamUser -groupid "a4f03b48-49ae-4f06-949f-81b4940e17b6" -user "$UPN"
}

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/remove-teamuser?view=teams-ps#:~:text=Remove%20an%20owner%20or%20member,hour%20before%20changes%20are%20reflected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/remove-teamuser?view=teams-ps#:%7E:text=Remove%20an%20owner%20or%20member,hour%20before%20changes%20are%20reflected).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Kartheek R,

I've used the answer above but modified it a bit to get it to work for me.

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams

$TeamGUID = "94865df5-97fd-1234-aaad-13555de4gt28"

$users = Get-TeamUser -GroupId $TeamGUID | where-object {$_.role -eq "member"} 

Foreach ($user in $users) { 
    $UPN = $user.User 
    Remove-TeamUser -groupid $TeamGUID -user $UPN
    Write-Host $UPN
}
```